# PHP HTTP Callback Asynchronous

Tags: php, http, asynchronous, curl

In my code I have PHP calling another API through an http post, which on success is supposed to do nothing but on failure is supposed to try again after some time. I need the code to finish running even on failure, and the retry code would be asynchronously run (after sleeping the delay). What would be the best way to achieve this.

Comment: What have you tried? What's not working?

Comment: just decided to use guzzle. im not sure if it's truly asynchronous but still working on it